# Primefaces schedule, event header color changed which is saved in DB

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using primefaces schedule, i want to change the color of event header which is saved in DB,

```
scheduleEvent.setStyleClass(".event-consultation .fc-event-skin .fc-event-head");
```

using this class i want to change the background-color property with the color saved in DB. how can i change color got from db here?

Answer (score 0):

I don't try it, but I guess the following should work:

```
<style type="text/css"> 
    .yourclass .fc-event-inner{
        background-color: #{yourBackBean.backGroundProperty};
    }    
</style>

....

scheduleEvent.setStyleClass("yourclass");
```

This way, you specify in-page CSS style that set as color-background the value of a backBean property that you previously loaded from DB.

Of course, you can create an application scope backBean and hardcode the EL in an external CSS file. Your choice.

Hope it helps!

## Edit to clarify

You have to put the `<style>` html node inside `<h:head>`. I just tested it in a project to change background color of a `<p:menuBar>` this way:

```
<h:head>
   ... some stuff of mine, not relevant

    <style type="text/css"> 
        .ui-menubar,.ui-menu-child,.ui-menu {
            background: #{sessionBean.bckgColor} !important;
         }
    </style>
</h:head>
```

And it works like a charm. I don't know what css style do you have to adapt to custom the event component of `<p:schedule>`, I am telling you how to write a custom CSS reading values from DB or whatever, using EL.

Maybe you need to use `!importan` css attribute to override original values as I did.

Comment: no man, i need to give two colors one to header and one to color, how to apply this?

Comment: where to add this style type?

Comment: I just edited my answer and tested my solution, please, try again.